# Replace empty dictionaries and lists from within pandas dataframe with Null

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, null

I have a dataframe that has lists and dictionaries contained within the columns.  How would I write a function that I can apply to columns that need to have the empty dictionaries and lists replaced with Null?

```
def transform_empty_cells(column):
    df.loc[(df.column == [] or {}),'column'] = 'Null'
```

Trying to make a neat function without having to write a line of code for each column.

It would be nice to map the function to the columns I need to apply it to.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Let us try use `bool`, since empty `dict` and `list` will be converted to False

```
df.loc[~df.column.astype(bool),'column']='null'
```

More columns

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Data':[[],[1]],'dct':[{},{1:2}]})
s=df.where(df.astype(bool))
s
Out[24]: 
  Data     dct
0  NaN     NaN
1  [1]  {1: 2}
```